# Integrate $\int \frac{t^7}{1+2t^4+t^8}dt$

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{t^7}{1+2t^4+t^8}dt=\int \frac{t^7}{(t^4+1)^2}dt$$

Can I use partial fractions in this stage? $t^4+1$? as it does not have root over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You can use partial fractions since $t^4 + 1 = (t^2 + \sqrt{2}t + 1)(t^2 - \sqrt{2}t + 1)$. But the answer below is much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

You have done the harder part.

$$t^7=t^4\cdot t^3$$

Write $t^4+1=u\iff t^4=u-1,4t^3\ dt=du$